# NodeJS binary modules vs those written in JS

Tags: mongodb, module, binary, driver, database

Yeah, I'm just wondering whether is it a good idea to use a MySQL or MongoDB driver written in pure JS.. I mean, it shouldn't be problem when running a small app with small db for 100 users / month, but what about heavy load / really huge DBs?

Aren't there any professional MySQL and Mongo drivers for NodeJS that I can compile? The performance of these should be way much better.

Or am I wrong about this? For example, Mongoose uses a driver written in pure JS. Is that good enough to efficiently query 500 million documents?

Any suggestion / advice would be appreciated!

Thanks

EDIT:

So thanks for the response guys. Well I'm still a but unsure about this :).
I mean, writing drivers in Python or Java or even C# surely makes sense, but those languages are much more powerful and faster than JS.

Here is what makes me worried:

My MySQL driver (written in pure JS) executes the query SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table in 300-400ms. If I execute the exact same query from MySQL shell, it takes 20ms.

I use an ORM (JugglingDB) which makes use of https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql module. The 300ms is the raw query query execution time, as printed in debug mode.

Why do we see such a big difference? Is it the ORM, or Node/JS or the driver is too slow?

Comment: The size of the database should have no impact on the performance of the drivers if your queries are reasonable.

Comment: Are those languages faster in ways that matter for your tests? It seems like you need to do some more performance testing. Maybe NodeJS isn't a great fit.

Comment: There are lies, damn lies and benchmarks: http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u64/javascript.php 

How are you connecting to MySQL in the driver?  Is it via the network that may account for the time difference, have you tested locally connecting to the socket rather than via tcp?

Answer (score 1):

Most MongoDB drivers are written in the language that they are used with. The Python driver is written in Python, the Perl driver in Perl. There are a few exceptions, as the PHP driver is written in C and the Python driver as an optional C extension to speed things up.

The node-mongodb-native driver is written all in JavaScript: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native. It make sense as the NodeJS platform is optimised for this and there should be no adverse effects.